# Obwohl and wenngleich

Tags: conjunction

Can i substitute obwohl with wenngleich? I always see ' wenngleich' in books.

1. Er geht zum Urlaub nach Spanien, wenngleich er nicht genug Geld hat.
2. Er geht zum Urlaub nach Spanien, obwohl er nicht genug Geld hat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can substitute "obwohl" with "wenngleich". But "wenngleich" is very oldfashioned and uncommon, so i wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: There is a Bach cantata I learned in choir that goes "obgleich sehr wieder uns die Feinde toben...". Same meaning, right? Also old-fashioned?

Comment: Same - Bach died in 1750. His cantatas are no reference for modern German ;)